# I need help on jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok, so, I have a question.
I am getting the element ID like this.

```
<td id="ctl00_cphRoblox_lstItemsForResale_ctrl1_Td1" class="PriceBuyContainer">
```

document.getElementById("ctl00_cphRoblox_lstItemsForResale_ctrl1_Td1")
And this is below it.

```
<div class=" roblox-buy-now btn-primary btn-small PurchaseButton " data-item-id="168167114" data-item-name="Wanwood Visor" data-userasset-id="1941846042" data-product-id="20655974" data-expected-price="114" data-asset-type="Hat" data-expected-currency="1" data-expected-seller-id="6141596" data-bc-requirement="0" data-seller-name="laughableblox">
    Buy Now
    <span class="btn-text">Buy Now</span>
</div>
```

How would I get `data-expected-price="NUMBERHERE"` by using?

```
document.getElementById("ctl00_cphRoblox_lstItemsForResale_ctrl1_Td1")`
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_getattribute.asp

Comment: Just a friendly note, putting "I need help" or similar in your title doesn't get you any brownie points here on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use JQuery's **[.data() function](http://api.jquery.com/data/)**. First you can grab the `td` element via jQuery:

```
var el = $("#ctl00_cphRoblox_lstItemsForResale_ctrl1_Td1");
```

Then find it's first child element and use use .data() to return the expected-price data attribute's value:

```
alert(el.find('> div').data('expected-price'));
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nuR3j/)**

Comment: Omg, thank you so much! :D I've been trying to figure this out for days now, thank you!